# Declaring an array of functions of type void C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a few functions that return `void`.  I made pointers to these functions and wanted to have an array of these functions:

Why does this code work:

```
#include <cstdio>
using std::puts;

void tell() {
  puts("hi");
};

void slap() {
  puts("goodbye");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  void (*tp)() = tell;
  void (*sp)() = slap;

  void(*funcs[])() = {tp, sp};
  for (auto point:funcs) {
    point();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try this code with out specifying a pointer in `funcs` (i.e. `void(funcs[])() = {tp, sp};`  I get `" error: 'funcs' declared as array of functions of type 'void ()' "`  Which is exactly what they are - so why is that an error?

I also don't get the syntax, wouldn't the `()` at the end of `void(*funcs[])()` indicate actually calling a function?

Comment: `void *x;` would be a pointer to object type. `void (*x)()` is a pointer to function type. That's just what pointers to function look like. The extra parentheses around `(*x)` are necessary because `void *x()` is parsed as `void *(x())` , a declaration of function returning `void *`.

Comment: Your code didn't compile, I have fixed it. If possible use copy-paste to avoid transcription errors that might obfuscate your question.

Comment: Better use typedef to declare a function pointer first, then use arrays of them. That would look better =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ Standard 8.3.5/10 says:

> There shall be no arrays of functions, although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

The declaration of "`funcs`" must be read using the "spiral rule":

`funcs[]`: `funcs` is an array

`*funcs[]`: `funcs` is an array of pointers

`(*funcs[])()`: `funcs` is an array of pointers to functions with no parameters

`void (*funcs[])()`: `funcs` is an array of pointers to functions with no parameters returning `void`.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can declare it explicitly like this:

```
void (*actions[5])();
```

But this is <strike>nearly</strike> unreadable.
To make it more readable use a typedef.

```
typedef void(*Action)();    // Action is the typename for a pointer
                            // to a function return null and taking
                            // no parameters.

Action   actions[5];        // An array of 5 Action objects.
```

Or for your purposes:

```
int main()
{
     Action   actions[] = {&tell, &slap};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the asterisk, `void (funcs[])()` declares an array of functions rather than array of *pointers* to functions. The latter is allowed in the C++ grammar while the former is not.

[dcl.array]/p1:

> `T` is called the array element type; this type shall not be a reference type, the (possibly cv-qualified) type `void`, **a function type** or an abstract class type.

The contents of the initializer-list (`{tp, sp}`) are functions but they are converted to pointers via the function-to-pointer conversion:

[conv.func]/p1

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the function.

Note that C++ also doesn't allow an array of references.

---

> I also don't get the syntax, wouldn't the `()` at the end of `void(*funcs[])()` indicate actually calling a function?

No, this is a declaration of an array type. The `()` is part of the construction of the type which specifies the argument list of the function. The entire type indicates *"an array of pointers to functions which take zero arguments (`()`) and return `void`"*. It may become clearer with the use of a type alias:

```c++
using void_f = void (*)();
void_f funcs[] = {tp, sp};
```

Comment: So for an array of function pointers they all need the same return type and the same type / amount of arguments?

Comment: @Startec Yes, the return type and parameter list must all be the same.

Answer (score -1):

use like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void (*tp)() = tell;
    void (*sp)() = slap;

    void (*funcs[])() = {tp, sp};
    for (void (*point)():funcs)
    {
        point;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to the OP, posting code without any annotation/explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: The question is about what happens when the `*` is removed from the line `void (*funcs[])() = {tp, sp};` .   You have pointed out a mistake on the line after; presumably this was some sort of transcription error