# Why is an asterisk optional when defining the type of a single function pointer but mandatory when that function pointer is an array element?

Tags: c++

The compiler is permissive in allowing interchanging of "function" and "function pointer"  when defining a single function parameter (optional asterisk in `typedef`), but strict when these function pointers are elements of arrays (mandatory asterisk in `typedef`):

```
typedef void(Action)();
// typedef void(*Action)();

// Works with either typedef
void doAction(Action f) {
  f();
}

// Only works with latter typedef
void doFirstAction(Action f_array[2]) {
  f_array[0]();
}
```

clang 15 output:

```
error: 'f_array' declared as array of functions of type 'Action' (aka 'void ()')
void doFirstAction(Action f_array[2]) {
                                 ^
```

I'd expect these asterisk rules to be consistent between single functions and arrays of functions, where each `typedef` would work for either none or both cases.

I understand that this rule is part of the C++ standard:

> There shall be no arrays of functions, although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

But I assume there's a similar rule about how only "function pointers" and not just "functions" can be passed to other functions, yet there's more flexibility in syntax for that case.

Follow-up to: [Declaring an array of functions of type void C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643245/declaring-an-array-of-functions-of-type-void-c)

Comment: When you define a function and its **parameter** has a function type, then the type of the **parameter** is adjusted to pointer-to-function. This has nothing to do with `typedef`. Types of other things (variables or struct fields or anything else) are not adjusted, whether you use `typedef` or not.

Comment: Except when used as the operand of `sizeof` or the `&` operator, an array decays to a pointer to its first element. So, if you had an array of functions, which decays into a pointer to the first function in that array, how would you distinguish that array from a single function?

Comment: I think the standard is clear enough. To avoid a lot of those issues I usually use std::vector<std::function<void()>> (or std::array) nowadays. This makes it also much more clear what you want to do with the array since you can pass it by const reference explictly and you can even have functions returning such an array.  And to me one added advantage is you can also add lambda's with captures to such an array.

Comment: Great info about: 1) Parameters of function type are automatically adjusted to pointer-to-function. 2) Pointer to function vs array of functions is ambiguous. 3) Using `std::function`.

Question: **Is there a use for just the non-pointer function type?** If not, then it seems like the syntax would be more ergonomic and consistent if the non-asterisk notation was the only way to refer to functions. Would you consider these two redundant forms to refer to functions as a language design mistake?